# Does making the following substitution rotate the axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

We have the function $(x-y)(x+y)=1$ and we substitute $x'=x-y, y'=x+y$ and graph the function on the $x'$ and $y'$ axis.  Exactly what does this do? It looks like is that $x',y'$ are rotated 45 degrees from $x,y$.

But the question is: why does this work? How can I regraph the function in terms of x,y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \pmatrix{x' \\ y'} = \pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1} \pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix{x-y \\ x+y}$$

Rotation matrices look like $$\pmatrix{\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)}$$

Plugging in $45^\circ$, yields $\pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$.  Then just notice that $$\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1}=\sqrt{2}\pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$$

So your transformation not only rotates the axes by $45^\circ$ but also stretches them by $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You might want to add this is defined as a similitude of angle $\dfrac\pi4$ and ratio $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 0):

It is a scaled rotation, yes. It rotates points $(x, y)$ by 45 degrees but also scales them outward by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$. More generally the scaled rotation matrix is:$$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix} = s \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}s~x~\cos\theta - s~y~\sin\theta\\s~x~\sin\theta + s~y~\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$In this case $\theta = \pi/4$ and so $\cos\theta =\sin\theta = \sqrt{1/2};$ with $s = \sqrt{2}$.

To invert it, you simply do the inverse rotation, $\cos\theta = -\sin\theta = \sqrt{1/2}$ with $s = \sqrt{1/2},$ in other words $$\frac 12 ( x' + y' ) = \frac 12 ((x - y) + (x + y)) = x \\
\frac 12 ( y' - x' ) = \frac 12 ((x + y) - (x - y)) = y.$$So those combinations will handily invert the transformation for you.

In any case, the shapes you're studying are called **hyperbolas**, and are one of the conic sections.